# Why is checkout permission denied on new folder creation for CVS?

Tags: configuration, permissions, cvs

We generally access our CVS server via Eclipse.  One of our teammates, `steveo` created a new package `Testing` under our Java `src` folder for project `ProjectName`.

Afterwards, this caused failures with all checkouts for `ProjectName`.

> The server reported an error while performing the "cvs checkout" command.
>
> : cvs checkout: failed to create lock directory for `/app/cvs/repository/Main/ProjectName/src/Testing' (/app/cvs/repository/Main/ProjectName/src/Testing/#cvs.lock): Permission denied
>
> : cvs checkout: failed to obtain dir lock in repository `/app/cvs/repository/Main/ProjectName/src/Testing'
>
> : cvs [checkout aborted]: read lock failed - giving up

I putty'd to the CVS server and did an `ls -l` on the `src` folder

> drwxrwxr-x 5 root    cvs 4096 May 19 12:05 com
>
> drwxrwxr-x 3 steveo  steveo 4096 May 19 12:05 Testing

I `sudo su`, backed up to the project folder, and ran `chgrp -R cvs ProjectName`.

> drwxrwxr-x 5 root    cvs 4096 May 19 12:05 com
>
> drwxrwxr-x 3 steveo  cvs 4096 May 19 12:05 Testing

This has solved the issue for now... until another user creates a package.

**What is causing this and how do I default them all to `cvs` instead?**

The answers to [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904458/cvs-error-failed-to-create-lock-directory-permission-denied) were not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and posting the answer for posterity.

I was originally going to set the repository folder to group `cvs` and make it sticky via `chmod g+s /app/cvs/repository/`, but that is not recursive and I don't know that I want to mess with that.

Default group id (GID) was not `cvs` for the users.  The solution is a bit of a workaround as we're using Active Directory as our account login.  Luckily, we're only using this server for CVS, which makes the solution simple.

This must be done for each account and each new account.

1. Make sure the account has attempted a log-in against CVS via Eclipse/RAD (and checked out a project, perhaps).  This creates the user profile under home.
2. `sudo su`
3. `cd \home\{username}`
4. Since we have nothing else going on in it, `echo "newgrp cvs" >> .profile`

That will set the default group to `cvs` for the offending accounts on log-in and I can call it a day... and eventually migrate to Git / BitBucket.